# Existence of convergent subsequences for all values in range?

Tags: sequences-and-series, soft-question, gn.general-topology

Consider sequence $s(n) = \sin{nx}$. Are there values of $x$ for which the following holds: For every $y \in \[-1,1\]$ there is a subsequence of $s(n)$ converging to $y$? (Or perhaps just for the open interval...) Someone hypothesised that the answer is yes, and further that every $x$ that is relatively irrational with $\pi $ has this property.

The question I am more interested in is the generalised version of this to arbitrary sequences. What are necessary and sufficient conditions for a sequence having subsequences converging to any point in the set of values the sequence visits? Does it have anything to do with properties like the function $f(n)$ being ergodic or mixing?

(suggestions for tags welcome in comments)

Comment: The answer to the question in your 1st paragraph is yes. As for $f$ being 'mixing' or 'ergodic'... notice those two notions do not apply in their usual form to functions $\mathbb N\to [-1,1]$, say.

Comment: Yes, I meant properties "like" mixing and ergodic. Sequences with the property I'm talking about seem to "bounce all over the place forever" in much the same way mixing functions do...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More conventional language:  Are there values of $x$ such that the sequence $\sin(nx)$ is dense in the interval $[-1,1]$.  The answer is yes, almost all $x$ have this property, in particular all $x$ such that $x/\pi$ is irrational.

See Weyl's Criterion
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_criterion
for something (equidistributed) that implies much more than merely dense.  And $nx$ mod 1 is equidistributed in $[0,1]$ if $x$ is irrational.

Comment: Is being dense in the interval enough to guarantee that there is a subsequence that converges to any point in the interval? I wouldn't have thought so...

Comment: @Seamus: what do you think the definition of "dense" is?  [I suppose without Axiom of Choice you could give alternate definitions.  But in this case we can always do a "choose the first $n$ such that..." argument and avoid it.]

Comment: There is a nice proof of this result using Fourier Analysis.  See T.W. Korner's *Fourier Analysis*, which I highly recommend in it's own right.  

Comment: I had an incorrect comment earlier. Sorry. I misread the condition as that every value of the sequence was a limit of a subsequence, as opposed to every value in [-1,1] being a limit of a subsequence. 

Answer (score 1):

Here is a typical sufficient condition: If for a sequence $a_n$, one has $\lim a_{n+1}-a_n = 0$, then every number between $\lim inf a_n$ and $\lim sup a_n$ is a limit of $a_n$.
Thus, if a sequence satisfies this condition, and in addition, $inf a_n = \lim inf a_n$, and $sup a_n = \lim sup a_n$, then every element of $a_n$ is a limit of $a_n$.